# Как сделать так, чтобы в углу окна в vim отображалась вводимая команда?

Tags: vim

Посоветовали установить плагин vim-sensible. По умолчанию в vim в нижнем правом углу отображалась вводимая команда, но после установки плагина эта функция исчезла
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Вот в этом месте отображалась вводимая команда, например F3o или "a3y*

Файл `.vimrc`:

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'tpope/vim-sensible'
call plug#end()
```

Comment: М.б. плагин отключает `'showcmd'`,  и стоит попробовать эту опцию включить `set showcmd` после запуска плагина? `:h showcmd`

Comment: Hobo-mts, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Как предположил [hobo-mts](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/204267/hobo-mts), нужно ввести `:set showcmd`